# React localhost page is blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to update my localhost page while working on a react project and it just turned blank. I get no errors on the code itself, but the page turned blank. Tried opening on a different port but it didn't work.

I'm trying to make an expense tracker, if that helps you at all.

App.js

```
import ExpenseItem from "./components/ExpenseItem";

function App() {

  const expenses = [
    {
      id: 'e1',
      title: 'Toilet Paper',
      amount: 94.12,
      date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
    },
    { id: 'e2', title: 'New TV', amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
    {
      id: 'e3',
      title: 'Car Insurance',
      amount: 294.67,
      date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
    },
    {
      id: 'e4',
      title: 'New Desk (Wooden)',
      amount: 450,
      date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Let's get started!</h2>
      <ExpenseItem title={expenses[0].title}
        amount={expenses[0].amount}
        date={expenses[0].date}>
      </ExpenseItem>

      <ExpenseItem title={expenses[1].title}
        amount={expenses[1].amount}
        date={expenses[1].date}>
      </ExpenseItem>

      <ExpenseItem title={expenses[2].title}
        amount={expenses[2].amount}
        date={expenses[2].date}>
      </ExpenseItem>

      <ExpenseItem title={expenses[3].title}
        amount={expenses[3].amount}
        date={expenses[3].date}>
      </ExpenseItem>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ExpenseItem.css'

class ExpenseItem extends Component {
    //state = {}

    render(props) {

        return (
            <div className='expense-item'>
                <div>{props.date.toISOString()}</div>
                <div className='expense-item__description'>
                    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                    <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

ExpenseItem.css

```
.expense-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #4b4b4b;
}

.expense-item__description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex: 1;
}

.expense-item h2 {
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 1rem;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    color: white;
}

.expense-item__price {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #40005d;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

@media (min-width: 580px) {
    .expense-item__description {
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .expense-item__description h2 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }

    .expense-item__price {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share any error on browser console

Answer (score 1):

If your not opposed to doing functional components this should fix your issue.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./ExpenseItem.css";

const ExpenseItem = ({ title, date, amount }) => {
  return (
    <div className="expense-item">
      <div>{date.toISOString()}</div>
      <div className="expense-item__description">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <div className="expense-item__price">${amount}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```